# Creating facets for custom contents added by CCK in apache Solr module

Tags: 6, search

I was unable to create Facet for a CCK field, in the sense that for a specific CCK content type i was unable to group.

This could be summarised as my problem statement

Ex. CCK Field - Article Author

Actual Result :
No Group (No of Search Records)
Expected:

- Author 1 (2)
- Author 2 (5)

etc....

This is my primary concern, I need to create facet for the custom content types.

Please let me know if any of you have previous experiences with implementing Apache Solr for Drupal. Also let me know your kind suggestions and feedback.

My drupal version is 6.22.

Note: Based on my googling experiment i set the CCK field type in question as text and not string but still didn't help me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get this done with good assistance from one of the module's maintainer.. [This](http://drupal.org/node/1344356) is the issue list query comprising further details and some sample code. Hope this servers of some help to anyone using solr search.

Cheers!!